# How do i add openssl library in android studio?

Tags: android, encryption, android-ndk, openssl, java-native-interface

I want to implement AES and RSA encryption in my project using ndk(not using java API).by brief study i coming to know that i need to add openssl for achieving my task. i downloaded library from here [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/source/). but that contains plenty of files. i am confused what to do with that.is there anything i need to do to use library or is there any better approach other than openssl. please help me. i am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit system.

Comment: it seems you need to do a bit more that a brief study and more searching. Your question is either about searching for docs or some example which is a bit out of topic in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a script to build the Android libs, you should not look further than the official site: [wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android). You can easily find prebuilt binaries, if you can afford this security compromise.

You may prefer the Chromium fork (https://opensource.google.com/projects/boringssl) which is not 100% plug-and-play compatible with the upstream, but has been tuned for the needs and limitations of Android app, and is pretty well documented.